# viewWillAppear of parent triggered when second presented viewcontroller dismissed

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewwillappear

I have 3 viewcontrollers
let's say AVC, BVC and CVC

First I present BVC from AVC and then present CVC from BVC

So the hierarchy would be AVC->BVC->CVC.

When I dismiss CVC from BVC, `viewWillAppear` of AVC is triggered, how can I prevent `viewWillAppear` of AVC getting called?

Thanks

**UPDATE**
First present (in AVC)

```
BTViewController *BTVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BTVCIns"];
__weak BTViewController *weakBTVC = BTVC;
BTVC.dismissAction = ^{[weakBuyTicketVC dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];};
[BTVC setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext];
[self presentViewController:BTVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Second present (in BVC)

```
PMViewController *PMVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PMVCIns"];
__block PMViewController *blockPMVC = PMVC;
blockPMVC.dismissAction = ^{[blockPMVC dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];};
blockPMVC.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:PMVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: How are you presenting each of the view controllers?

Comment: I am using normal method
[AVC presentViewController:BVC animated:YES completion:nil]
then in BVC
[BVC presentViewController:CVC animated:YES completion:nil]

Comment: @Renandus: can you show us the code?

Comment: You are presenting all 3 view controllers as full-screen modal, and viewWillAppear of view controller A is being called when you dismiss C? (And as a result, B is shown, but A remains fully covered?) That doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

From the [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/PresentingaViewController.html)

> When presenting a view controller using the UIModalPresentationFullScreen style, UIKit normally removes the views of the underlying view controller after the transition animations finish. You can prevent the removal of those views by specifying the **UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext** style instead. You might use that style when the presented view controller has transparent areas that let underlying content show through.

Since you are using `UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext`, iOS considers that BVC may have transparent areas which expose AVC, hence when BVC appears it is possible that AVC is also going to appear, so `viewWillAppear` is called.